# Angular Material mat-form-field conditional appearance

Tags: angular-material, mat-form-field

This seemed like something simple but for some reason I cant get this to work. So, I want the appearance of the `mat-form-field` to change based on some condition, for example, if the filed is disabled it should be `none` and if it is enabled it should be `standard`.

So for the most simple scenario, how to get this to work:

```
<mat-form-field  appearance="'true' ? 'standard' : 'none'">
...
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
   <mat-form-field [appearance]="true ? 'outline': 'fill'">
    ...
   </mat-form-field>
```